# Clear IE 11 Cache or system memory refresh?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, caching, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

In our web application, a Manager can change someone's(xyz) status to 'Vacation' or 'Sick', if someone tries to assign work to xyz, xyz person will not show in the drop down of the available employees to assign work to, but when the manager changes the status back to Available, Other managers/users can see xyz in Available employees drop down except for the Manager who made the status change. Once the affected manager restarts the system then he/she can see the user is available.
I tried clearing the IE Cache - ctrl + shift + delete ,  ctrl + R. nothing worked. My job is to somehow avoid the system reboot. What kind of cache I need to clear. files under temp folder? or clear the DNS cache or something else.